# Peek ahead for a digit (expl3) – or any regex, for that matter

Tags: expl3

Is there an easy way to peek ahead for a digit? Something like

```
\peek_charcode:NTF [0-9]
```

The approach to nest 10 `\peek_charcode:NTF` is quite cumbersome.

I want to match digits only. Digits, parenthesis and others share the same catcode.

Comment: I don't really know if there are options, but I think that some sort of `\peek_case:nTF { {1}{..} {2}{..} } { .. } { .. }` would be nice (although the name is not correct since all `case` functions are expandable, something of that kind would be nice).

Comment: @Manuel We've had a request for such a thing but it really doesn't fit with TeX's way of working that well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standing on the shoulders of giants and extending the idea of Manuel, I came up with this solution.
I think, a `\regex_peek:nTF` would be so versatile that it should be added to `l3regex`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF { no }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mh_regex_peek:nTF #1 #2 #3
  {
    \peek_catcode:NTF ##
      {#3}
      {
        \regex_match:noTF 
        { \A the\  (character|letter)\ (#1) \Z }
        { \token_to_meaning:N \l_peek_token } {#2} {#3}
      }
  }

\mh_regex_peek:nTF { [0-9] } { digit: ~ } { no ~ digit: ~ } 1 \par
\mh_regex_peek:nTF { [0-9] } { digit: ~ } { no ~ digit: ~ } 2 \par
\mh_regex_peek:nTF { [0-9] } { digit: ~ } { no ~ digit: ~ } ( \par
\mh_regex_peek:nTF { [0-9] } { digit: ~ } { no ~ digit: ~ } {1} ~ (group) \par
\mh_regex_peek:nTF { [a] } { is ~ letter ~ a: ~ } { not ~ letter ~ a: ~ } 1 \par
\mh_regex_peek:nTF { [a] } { is ~ letter ~ a: ~ } { not ~ letter ~ a: ~ } a \par
\mh_regex_peek:nTF { [abc] } { is ~  a,  ~ b ~  or ~ c: ~ } { not ~  a,  ~ b ~  or ~ c: ~ } b \par
\mh_regex_peek:nTF { a|b|c } { is ~  a,  ~ b ~  or ~ c: ~ } { not ~ a,  ~ b ~  or ~ c: ~ } b \par
\mh_regex_peek:nTF { a|b|c } { is ~  a,  ~ b ~  or ~ c: ~ } { not ~ a,  ~ b ~  or ~ c: ~ } e \par
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: Made more robust, by filtering out #

**Edit**: Switched to the regex `{ \A the\  (character|letter)\ (#1) \Z }`. If anybody knows a nice way to convert `\l_peek_token` into a token list, then I could get rid of this workaround. **PS.** It seems that egreg had a very similar idea at the same time.

**PPS** This solution is being used in mhchem v4.00, now.

Comment: The `\cs_set_nopar:Npn` should be also `protected`, because it's not expandable. In any case, what's the intention of expanding `\token_to_meaning:N \l_peek_token`? Is it correct?

Comment: If `\l_peek_token` has been set to `0`, then `\token_to_meaning:N \l_peek_token` will expand to `the character 0`, so the search string `a` will match.

Comment: @egreg: Can you explain? I added another example `    \mh_regex_peek:nTF { [a] } { not ~ letter ~ a: ~ } { is ~ letter ~ a: ~ } 0 \par` that works for me.

Comment: Did you try the last one with `a` instead of `0`? Yes, I was wrong in my comment above, but only because of the category codes assigned by `\token_to_meaning:N`

Comment: @egreg, **I** was wrong. Mixed up T and F clause. Fixed it. Is does not work. But why?

Comment: @mhchem Because of what I said: `a` matches `the character 0`, doesn't it?

Comment: @egreg, oh now I get it! Can you help me, how to put the content of `\l_peek_token` into `\regex_match`?

Comment: May be create a `\__mh_peek_filter:w` which does a few checks and decides what is “inside” `\l_peek_token` (and for instance removes the ``the character `` part in case it's a character) and then calls `\regex_match:noTF` accordingly?

Answer (score 4):

A starting point (coming from someone who knows nothing about the deep internals of `expl3`, this, to me, just *seems to work*). I would use `\token_case:NnTF` but that function doesn't exist.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mh_peek_case:nTF #1 #2 #3
 {
  \cs_set_nopar:Npn \__mh_peek_case:w
   {
    \tl_case:NnTF \l_peek_token { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
  \peek_after:Nw \__mh_peek_case:w
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \checkfordigit { }
 {
  \mh_peek_case:nTF
   {
    {0}{} {1}{} {2}{} {3}{} {4}{}
    {5}{} {6}{} {7}{} {8}{} {9}{} 
   }
   { Next ~ token ~ is ~ a ~ digit: ~ }
   { Next ~ token ~ is ~ not ~ a ~ digit: ~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\checkfordigit 1 \par
\checkfordigit 2 \par
\checkfordigit A \par 
\checkfordigit -- \par
\end{document}
```

In case you don't care if it's `\checkfordigit{1}` you could define it just with `\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1} \tl_case:NnTF \l_tmpa_tl { .. } { .. } { .. }`.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of `\peek_regex:NTF` is very nice, but it has a problem: the expansion of `\token_to_meaning:N \l_peek_token`, when the following token is `0` is

```
the character 0
```

so in your case

```
\mh_peek_regex:nTF { a } { true } { false } 0
```

will return `true`, because `a` matches `the character 0`.

If you limit yourself to looking for characters and not other tokens, then the idea can be made to work, still allowing ranges in the first argument:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF { nV }
\tl_new:N \l__mh_char_peek_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mh_char_peek:nTF #1 #2 #3
 {
  \peek_catcode:NTF ##
   { #3 }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l__mh_char_peek_tl { \token_to_meaning:N \l_peek_token }
    \regex_match:nVTF { \A the } \l__mh_char_peek_tl
     {
      \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A the \s .* \s } { } \l__mh_char_peek_tl
      \regex_match:nVTF {#1} \l__mh_char_peek_tl {#2} {#3}
     }
     { #3 }
   }
 }

\mh_char_peek:nTF { [0-9] } { digit: ~ } { no ~ digit: ~ } 1 \par
\mh_char_peek:nTF { [0-9] } { digit: ~ } { no ~ digit: ~ } 2 \par
\mh_char_peek:nTF { [0-9] } { digit: ~ } { no ~ digit: ~ } ( \par
\mh_char_peek:nTF { [0-9] } { digit: ~ } { no ~ digit: ~ } {1} ~ (group) \par
\mh_char_peek:nTF { [0-9] } { digit: ~ } { no ~ digit: ~ } - \par
\mh_char_peek:nTF { a } { is ~ letter ~ a: ~ } { not ~ letter ~ a: ~ } 0 \par
\mh_char_peek:nTF { [a-z] } { is ~ letter ~ a: ~ } { not ~ letter ~ a: ~ } a \par

\end{document}
```

I check that the expansion of `\token_to_meaning:N \l_peek_token` starts with `the` and, in this case I know it will either be `the character <?>` or `the letter <?>` so I can remove the unwanted tokens from that expansion and do the correct check.

[image]

Tests for other tokens can go on with the appropriate `\peek_...:NTF` function.